# change html5 background video source

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I want to change background video source depending on the size of the window.
To minimize navigation traffic I don't want to change the video through CSS.

I tried to do this:

```
<script>
function chsrc() {
    var larghezza_browser = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    if ( larghezza_browser > 1540 ) {
        console.log('carico il video grande - larghezza: ' + larghezza_browser + 'px');
        document.getElementById("mp4_desktop").src="//sullimite.it/wp-content/themes/sullimite/fosco/modella_schermo_grande.mp4";
        document.getElementById("webm_desktop").src="//sullimite.it/wp-content/themes/sullimite/fosco/modella_schermo_grande.webm";
    } else {
        console.log('carico il video piccolo - larghezza: ' + larghezza_browser + 'px');
        document.getElementById("mp4_desktop").src="//sullimite.it/wp-content/themes/sullimite/fosco/modella_schermo_piccolo.mp4";
        document.getElementById("webm_desktop").src="//sullimite.it/wp-content/themes/sullimite/fosco/modella_schermo_piccolo.webm";
    }
}
</script>
```

Added `<body onload="chsrc()" onresize="chsrc()">`

And the html:

```
<video autoplay loop muted id="video_home">
<source id="mp4_desktop" type="video/mp4" />
<source id="webm_desktop" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

In chrome console it seems to work but I can't see the video
[html chrome developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kXDk.jpg)

[console log chrome developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5vhk.jpg)

do you know what I'm wrong about?

Thanks

Fosco

Answer (score 1):

HTML media elements have to be loaded, after you change the source do this...

```
//this line loads the media for the given id
document.getElementById("webm_desktop").load();
```

Then you can use the [oncanplaythrough](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplaythrough.asp) event listener to do something after the media has completely loaded and can play through the entire file.

```
document.getElementById("webm_desktop").oncanplaythrough(
//play the video here
//do something here too if you want
);
```

That should work for you

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand how to do what you are suggesting to me.

Comment: @FoscoVentura see my edit. I explain the two lines in more detail.

Comment: I am not able to do what you said but I solved the problem changing getElementById from webm_desktop to video_home. I also removed mp4 and used only webm

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that, some browsers support webm but I don't think its close to the majority yet. If you HAVE to do only one format it would be best to use MP4 as I believe that is the most widely supported format.

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution, it works for me:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video_home');
var source = document.getElementById('video_source');

function chsrc(event) {
   var winSize = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
   if (winSize <= 768) {
      source.setAttribute('src', 'video_mobile.mp4');
      video.load();
   } else {
      source.setAttribute('src', 'video.mp4');
      video.load();
   }
}
```